# Ticking checkboxes - there must be a more elegant way than this?

Tags: jquery

I have a bunch of related checkboxes, with integer values. I'm trying to encompass the simple logic that:

- when you tick a box, all the boxes with a value <= should get automatically ticked.
- when you untick a box, all the boxes with a value > should get automatically unticked.

This is what I've got, which works, but takes up sixteen lines and looks a bit repetitive. Is there a better way?

```
$('.chk_level').click(function(event){
    var this_val        = parseInt( $(this).val() );
    var this_is_checked = $(this).is(':checked');
    $('.chk_level').each(function(i,chk){
        var $chk = $(chk);
        if ( this_is_checked ){
            if ( parseInt( $chk.val() ) <= this_val ){
                $chk.attr('checked', true);
            }
        }else{
            if ( parseInt( $chk.val() ) > this_val ){
                $chk.attr('checked', false);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No answer but I appreciate the username 'Wintermute', nice! Gibson fan?

Comment: Indeed :) Neuromancer's probably my favourite book...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your logic seems odd as if you are unchecking higher values, then you can make all checkboxes unchecked, and then only check the lower ones which are required. With this in mind the following works in the same way as your OP example:

```
$('.chk_level').click(function(e){
    var $el = $(this);
    $(".chk_level").prop("checked", false);
    var $chk = $(".chk_level").filter(function() {
        return parseInt($(this).val(), 10) <= parseInt($el.val(), 10);
    }).prop("checked", true);
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LKPT9/)

Comment: I KNEW there was an easier way. Yeah, same logic covers both scenarios. Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 3):

Using [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and checking/unchecking the elements in batches makes the code a little shorter:

```
$(".chk_level").click(function() {
    var predicate, $this = $(this),
        this_val = parseInt($this.val(), 10),
        this_is_checked = $this.is(":checked");
    if (this_is_checked) {
        predicate = function() {
            return parseInt($(this).val(), 10) <= this_val;
        };
    } else {
        predicate = function() {
            return parseInt($(this).val(), 10) > this_val;
        };
    }
    $(".chk_level").filter(predicate).prop("checked", this_is_checked);
});
```

Comment: The OPs current code goes through every checkbox and changes the `checked` attribute based on the value of the checkbox clicked - your code only checks or unchecks (if that makes sense !!!)

Comment: @ManseUK, you're absolutely right, my answer implements the algorithm described in the question but does not behave like the code therein. I'll see what I can do. Thanks :)

Comment: @ManseUK, on second thought (and third reading), it seems the questioner's code does not impact all the check boxes every time. The nested `if` statements look like they behave the same as the code in my answer.